# Memory loophole in quantum entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

How exactly the memory loophole/explanation is eliminated in quantum entanglement experiments. (Memory loophole is described below)

**Memory loophole -**

Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopholes_in_Bell_test_experiments#Memory_loophole)

Taking example of spin entanglement - the measurement of pairs create a spin imbalance that accumulates and influences measurement of subsequent pairs so that the net result still follows QM predictions due to conservation of angular momentum over a region of space/time. Because the memory accumulates over time, it does not require any FTL.

**The memory explanation only applies to statistical correlations** . The **anti-correlation** for all angles, is enforced strictly by "instantaneous conservation of angular momentum", and is predetermined.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43763/discussion-on-question-by-kpv-memory-loophole-in-quantum-entanglement).

Comment: +1, why so many  (5) downvotes?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my question in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgoWM4Jcl-s

Between 27:20 and 27:40 minutes, the speaker says that the memory loophole can be verified from the data itself. That is what I was expecting too.

(Superposition + QM probability) and memory loophole, both can give same final correlation as predicted by QM. In both the cases, the data can be randomly distributed. But interim data would fluctuate differently in the two cases.

If memory loophole is real, the data would be relatively more bound around the predicted value, due to balancing tendency.

With superposition + probability function, the interim data can sporadically fluctuate in wide ranges due to probabilistic nature.